# как избавиться от скрола в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно избавиться от скрола ? Появился такой двойной скрол как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Larix.Esuite.Module.Tasks.Desktop.View.TodayTasksWidgetView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" 
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <GroupBox x:Name="Container" Padding="5,2,5,2" Height="300">
        <Grid x:Name="LayOutGrid"  />
    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

помогите разобраться, как сделать один скрол ?

Comment: сначала было бы неплохо исправить Grid на DataGrid
и я не вижу у тебя где пишется название "Unerledigt" в GroupBox
и xaml код не соответствует тому, что показано на скиншоте а так то запихны ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Disabled" в GroupBox или DataGrid, тоесть туда где тебе нужно забрать скрол

Comment: Посмотрите при помощи Snoop'а, какие контролы показывают скроллбар. Из вашего примера этого не видно.

Comment: Ваш код не соответствует вашему скриншоту. Найдите тот код, который рисует этот список.